# Data from windows forms gets inserted multiple times in MySql

Tags: mysql, winforms, sql-insert

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. I made different methods for adding data to mysql, since there are different queries and I thought that was the problem. But now, after I type in data a second time, it multiplies when inserted.

Here's my code from mysql. I added FK to account table as well.

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
customer_id INT auto_increment,
social_security_no VARCHAR(12),
first_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(20),
adress VARCHAR(50),
phone_no VARCHAR(12),
PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE account(
account_no INT,
account_name VARCHAR(20),
account_balance DOUBLE,
customer_id INT
);

ALTER TABLE customer_login
ADD FOREIGN KEY(customer_id)
REFERENCES customer(customer_id);

CREATE TABLE customer_login(
social_security_no VARCHAR(12),
password INT,
customer_id INT 
);
```

EDIT: I updated my code. I changed my primary key to customer_id INT autoincrement in table customer and made it foreign key in the other tables. It still multiplies x8 when I insert the second customer.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AddCustomer();

        }
    private void AddCustomer()
    {
        string conn_string = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection_string"].ConnectionString;
        
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn_string);

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO customer (social_security_no, first_name, last_name, adress, phone_no)" +
            " VALUES (@social_security_no, @first_name, @last_name, @adress, @phone_no)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@social_security_no", socsecnoBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", firstnameBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", lastnameBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adress", adressBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_no",phonenoBox.Text);

            con.Open();

            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("query for inserting customer is executing " + i + " time");
                AddAccount();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

            
        // första query executes 
    }

   
    private void AddAccount()
    {
        string conn_string = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection_string"].ConnectionString;
        Random rndm = new Random();
        string accName = "Transaktionskonto";
        int accId = rndm.Next(2045823499);
        
        string bAlance = balanceBox.Text;
        double balance = Convert.ToDouble(bAlance);

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn_string);

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO account " +
            "SET account_no = @account_no, account_name = @account_name, account_balance = @account_balance, customer_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE social_security_no = @social_security_no)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_no", accId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_name", accName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_balance", balance);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@social_security_no", socsecnoBox.Text);

            con.Open();

            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("query for inserting account is executing " + i + " time");
                AddLogIn();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Något gick fel med kontouppgifter.");
            }
        }

            



    }

   

    private void AddLogIn()
    {
        string conn_string = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection_string"].ConnectionString;
        Random rndm = new Random();
        int password = rndm.Next(9999);
        string socNo = socsecnoBox.Text;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn_string);
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO customer_login SET social_security_no = @social_security_no, password = @password, customer_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE social_security_no = @social_security_no)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@social_security_no", socNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

            con.Open();

            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("query for inserting login is executing " + i + " time");
                MessageBox.Show("Du är nu kund! Ditt lösenord är " + password);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Något gick fel med inloggningsuppgifter.");
            }
        }
           

    }
```

Comment: Peobably it has nothing to do with your current problem, but please do not hard code the connectionstring, instead store it once in the configuration file and read it from there. Another point to change is the missing _using_ statement around your MySqlConnection object to ensure a safe disposal of the unmanaged resources contained in the object

Comment: thank you, I fixed the using statement and I stored the connection string in the configuration file instead! It still multiplies though.

Comment: If AddCustomer is the only point in your code where you insert this data then I suggest to use the debugger and put a breakpoint in the first lines of that method. So when the code reaches the breakpoint you can examine the call-stack window and see from where the multiple calls come. Probably you will understand the logic

Comment: If the table has really a primary key set on the _social_security_no_ then it is not possible that you could insert multiple records with the same primary key. In alternative (not optimal) you could add another column with autoincrement flag set and use that column as primarykey and add an unique index on the _social_security_no_ column

Comment: I added a pk customer_id instead. But it multiplies as well. I must have typed something wrong in mysql code?